# How do I update Anaconda on my chromebook

Tags: python, anaconda, chromebook

I have anaconda2 on my chromebook and I would like to update it, but I don't know how to reach anaconda navigator. I already have python3 installed on my chromebook. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just type

```
conda update conda
```

That's it. See this link for [reference](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/update-version/).